# Positioning Dynamic Element over Static Background Image

Tags: html, css

I have a banner section on a new page I'm working on. There is a static image background image of the div and then i have an absolutely positioned icon and image over the background image. There is a specific spot the icon and image need to be placed over the background image and it needs to always be in that position. How can i ensure that the icon and image are positioned over the map icon of my background image no matter the screen size. I developed off a standard of 1920x1080 but going to a bigger screen size causes it to move out from that placement. What is the best solution for this?

```css
#Banner {
  background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/w3CP-071823-04-Website-Concept_FranchisePage_HEADER_2.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10 and IE 11 */
  user-select: none;
  /* Standard syntax */
}

#Banner .container {
  width: 1400px;
  max-height: 350px;
  min-height: 350px;
  position: relative;
}

#Banner .container h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  width: 60%;
  line-height: 1;
}

#Banner .container .loc-icon {
  width: 14.5%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15.5%;
  top: 15%;
}

#Banner .container .loc-img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 16.25%;
  top: 18%;
  width: 13%;
  border: solid 0.75em #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="Banner">
  <div class="container">
    <h1><span class="care">Care</span><span class="patrol">Patrol</span> of [wpbb site:tagline]</h1>
    <div class="loc-marker">
      <img class="loc-icon" src="/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/w3CP-071823-04-Website-Concept_FranchisePage_Marker.svg" />
      <img class="loc-img" src="[wpbb site:acf_option type='image' name='owner_image' image_size='full' display='url']" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Correct Icon/Image placement over the background-image map section:
[image: Correct Placement on a 19020x1080 Screen]

In-Correct Icon/Image placement over the background-image map section:
[image: In-Correct Placement on a 5k screen Screen]

Answer (score 0):

I've had to solve this problem for a couple of projects now, and the way I like to do it is to express the coordinates in terms of percentage of the background image. That way the placement can be agnostic to the dimensions of the image and restyling is easy. Place the background image and the element to be placed inside a container div. If you have to style the image size, do so on the container div rather than the img element, so that they are the exact same size. Absolutely position your element as needed, optionally translating by -50% on x and y so the center of the element is at the cooridnate. The example below places a red square at the exact center of the image.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

.image {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%; 
}

.placed { 
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/600/200" class="image"/>
<div class="placed"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The icon and image is already being expressed in percentages.

`#Banner .container .loc-icon {
  width: 14.5%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15.5%;
  top: 15%;
}

#Banner .container .loc-img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 16.25%;
  top: 18%;
  width: 13%;
  border: solid 0.75em #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}`

Comment: @ConnorDensmore So what's the issue? Is it being placed incorrectly? If the percentages are correct then my method should work.